# Jquery Tabs Cookies

Tags: jquery, plugins, tabs, cookies

I am trying to use the Jquery cookie plugin to remember the last selected tab.

I can't seem to get it to work.Do i need anything else apart from the jquery lib and cookie plugin???

This is the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#tabletabscampaigns > ul").tabs({ remote: true, cache: true });
$("#tabletabscampaigns").tabs({selected: 0, cookie: { expires: 30}  }); 
    });       
</script>

<div id="tabletabscampaigns" style="float:left; width:895px; margin-top:20px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the options you have:  selected:0

By default it will always show this tab even with cookies

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using [this Tabs plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs), make sure that you have the correct [Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

Answer (score 0):

in the plugin documention it states not to use selected with cookie plugin.